# diophantine equations over $Q_p$

Tags: diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory

I need to show that there is no trivial solution to the equation $3x^2+2y^2-z^2=0$ in $Q_3$
So can I look at solutions in $F_3$ and if I didn't find any then assume that there is no solution in $Q_3$?

$3x^2+2y^2-z^2=0 (mod3) => 2y^2+2z^2=0 (mod3) => y^2+z^2=0 (mod3)$ but there are no such y and z in $F_3$ that satisfy the equation.

I have already shown that if there's a solution to the equation $(a,b,c)$ in $Q_3^3$ then there is one with $|c|_3=1$
and necessarily $|3a^2|<|2b^2|$, $|2b^2|=|c^2|$
and I need to conclude from that if there's any solution then there is one with $|a|\leq|b|$ and $|c|=1$
how can I conclude that?
and how does that help me in showing that there is no solution in $Q_3$

Comment: true I was afraid of that so $(a,0,0)$ could be an answer in $F_3^3$ but what can I know about the solution in $Q_3$ is it of the same form? or does it just mean that I can't try to prove it in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the equation is homogeneous, *if* there is a solution in $\mathbf Q_3^3$ besides $(0,0,0)$ then it can be *scaled* to a solution $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbf Z_3^3$ besides $(0,0,0)$.  Then you can divide through by the highest power of $3$ dividing $x$, $y$, and $z$ to make your solution $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbf Z_3^3$ have at least one coordinate in $\mathbf Z_3^\times$.

Only *now* do we reduce mod $3$ (you definitely can't do that at the beginning when you don't even know your coordinates are all in $\mathbf Z_3$).  We have
$$
3x^2 + 2y^2 - z^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow 2y^2 - z^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 3 \Longrightarrow y^2 + z^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 3.
$$
The only solution to that mod $3$ is $(0,0)$, so $y \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ and $z \equiv 0 \bmod 3$. Writing $y = 3y'$ and $z = 3z'$, the original equation becomes
$$
3x^2 + 2 \cdot 9y'^2 - 9z'^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow x^2 + 6y'^2 - 3z'^2 = 0,
$$
and reducing this mod $3$ gives us
$$
x^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 3,
$$
so $x \equiv 0 \bmod 3$.  This contradicts the property that
$x$, $y$, or $z$ is in $\mathbf Z_3^\times$.  Thus it is not true that the equation $3x^2 + 2y^2 - z^2 = 0$ has a solution in $\mathbf Q_3^3$ other than $(0,0,0)$: the only $3$-adic solution is $(0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $(x,y,z)$ is a non-trivial solution in $\Bbb Q_3$. Without loss of generality we may assume
that $y,z\in \Bbb Z_3^{\times}$. Thus
$$
3x^2+2y^2-z^2\equiv 0\bmod 3 
$$
implies that $2y^2\equiv z^2 \bmod 3$, or
$$
2\equiv \left( \frac{z}{y} \right)^2 \bmod 3.
$$
Here we use that $y^2$ has invertible image in $\Bbb F_3$.
However, $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$, which is a contradiction. So we are done.

Comment: is it the same if I say $2y^2-z^2=0 mod 3 =>2y^2+2z^2=0 mod 3 =>y^2+z^2=0 mod 3=>y^2=2z^2 mod 3=>(\frac{y}{z})^2=2 mod 3$?

Comment: In $\Bbb F_3$ we have $2y^2=z^2$, so then $2=(z/y)^2$. This is all.

Comment: and how can I show that if there's a a solution then there is one with $|a|\leq |b|$?